# SQL SERVER C# - performing data operations off of a custom audit table

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, azure

I'm a little stuck with finding an approach to perform DML operations off of a custom audit table.

I have a custom audit table on server A. I have a trigger setup to write any DML changes to a custom Audit table:

```
    [dbo].[data_forwarder_audit_table]
    [table_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [row_id] [bigint] NULL,
    [operation] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [time_stamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [primary_key] [varchar](255) NULL
```

So far so good, the triggers are working and I am getting the values expected in the audit table.

My thought process is:

1. Perform a SELECT query on the Audit Table.
2. Dynamically Query the changed row from the table_name by row_id
3. Based on the operation Insert,Update,Delete the changes to another SQL Database on another server

I need to consider performance (imagine that) and I need to dynamically get column names for the CRUD functions because there are quite a few tables that write changes to the audit table.

How should I approach this?

Thank you,
Ron

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have a trigger to track data changes...what do you want to happen next?

Comment: I need to push those changes to another SQL Server Database

Comment: If you set up replication on a table dml changes are replicated too.

Comment: I wanted to go replication but it says I need a Publisher, Distributor, and Subscriber. I just need to sync the changes...without the need for a third database.

Comment: @RSH distributor can be the same machine as the publisher or the subscriber. There are three roles but they don't have to be different databases.